# Loading huge data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a file in Azure Data Lake GEN2,containing around 30 columns and 0.7 billion rows.
Would like to understand what would be the best way to display this data in Power BI.
Below is what I have tried

1. Stored the data as parquet and then tried importing into Power BI but it fails with connection timeout issues
2. Published the Power BI in premium workspace and then tried refreshing from workspace - it fails here as well after 4 hours approx.
3. Created a view in Serverless SQL Pool and then tried accessing this view in Power BI but it fails with Timeout issues as well (was trying to create a live connection here). Note that we cannot increase timeout in Serverless SQL

What other approaches can be evaluated, as its crucial for me to show the full data in the report and there is no scope to roll up or group by. I need this data as just a one time load and not looking for any incremental options.

Comment: Good question! *Displaying* 21 bn numbers in a Power BI report makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Can you use direct query rather than import the data?? This use case is what direct query is designed for. You may have to move to Azure SQL DB or Dedicated Pool, and bring the data into the database and not as an external table

Answer (score 0):

Importing 30x700M dataset into PowerBI might be the wrong start here. Why? What are you trying to do with that giant flat table?

But, since you asked - https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/01/24/comparing-the-performance-of-importing-data-into-power-bi-from-adlsgen2-direct-and-via-azure-synapse-analytics-serverless/